# Is stream Reading can make and send Null to blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I use stream for file with: memory stream, stream readinng or file stream such as

```
byte[] buff = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(open.FileName);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buff);
```

and I want to send it to blob storage and at that point my blob is empty, is it because of reading file by stream or it refers to other problem such as miss configuration on blob or  CloudStorageAccount connection string.

Comment: Sorry but... what exactly is your question? I'm not understanding it.

Comment: Could it be possible that your stream is positioned at the end? Try doing `ms.Position = 0` just before you call the upload method. HTH.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I tried to call stream reading one time when I want to upload in blob and another time when I want to have some modification on file before storing on blob storage. I had no content I think it is because calling stream reading twice. and I have to wrote one line of code before uploading file in order to move back the pointer of file at the beginning and make position to zero

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks so much I think this is exactly right what you said. There are some situations when I want to call stream reading twice and I have to move position of pointer at the beginning before uploading file on storage: file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); OR  memorystream.Position = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the below code. No need to convert memory stream, You can pass stream to blob storage using Blob.UploadfromStream method.

```
StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountName"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountKey"]
                );
            CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);
            CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer contain = client.GetContainerReference("your container name");
            contain.CreateIfNotExists();
    CloudBlockBlob blob = contain.GetBlockBlobReference("your blob name");
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("your file"))
                    blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that your stream is positioned at `0` just before you start uploading to blob from that stream. As mentioned in the comments above, you could try the following:

```
ms.Position = 0
```

or

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```